# Am I need to set Auto Increment for column in order to generator identit work

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

This is my hbm file

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.quiz.online.Quiz" table="quiz" catalog="test">
        <id name="questionid" type="long">
            <column name="questionid" />
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>
         ...
```

I have set identity generator, but  when I insert values into db using this code

```
public String insertQuestion(String question,String answer1,String answer2,String answer3,String answer4,String correctanswer,String reason)
    {
        JSONObject obj=new JSONObject();
        try {
            Quiz quiz=new Quiz();
            quiz.setQuestion(question);
            quiz.setAnswer1(answer1);
            quiz.setAnswer2(answer2);
            quiz.setAnswer3(answer3);
            quiz.setAnswer4(answer4);
            quiz.setCorrectanswer(correctanswer);
            quiz.setReason(reason);

            QuizDAO dao=new QuizDAO();
            Transaction tx= dao.getSession().beginTransaction();
            dao.save(quiz);
            tx.commit();

            obj.put("status", "success");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            try {
                e.printStackTrace();
            JSONObject objexp=new JSONObject();
            objexp.put("status", "failure");
            return objexp.toString();
            } catch (Exception e2) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return obj.toString();
    }
```

it fails because `questionid` is `null`.

so it gives the following exception.

```
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not insert: [com.quiz.online.Quiz]
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.handledNonSpecificException(SQLStateConverter.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:114)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:64)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2176)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2656)
    at org.hibernate.action.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:71)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:279)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:321)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:204)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:130)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:210)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:195)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:50)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:93)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:563)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:551)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:547)
    at com.quiz.online.QuizDAO.save(QuizDAO.java:36)
    at com.quiz.services.DbUtil.insertQuestion(DbUtil.java:28)
    at com.quiz.services.Questions.insertQuestions(Questions.java:19)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.EntityParamDispatchProvider$TypeOutInvoker._dispatch(EntityParamDispatchProvider.java:138)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:67)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:154)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:111)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:71)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:111)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:63)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:543)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:502)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:493)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:308)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:314)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:849)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:454)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Field 'questionid' doesn't have a default value
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1078)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4120)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4052)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2503)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2664)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2815)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2155)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2458)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2375)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2359)
    at org.hibernate.id.IdentityGenerator$GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(IdentityGenerator.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:57
```

When I set autoincrement in the DB it is working. So inorder to `identity` generator to work, am I need to set `autoincrement` in `MySQL`

Comment: Does the actual SQL table have a primary key that is set to auto_increment?

Comment: @blackpanther I haven't set auto_increment for the actual table

Comment: You may want to do that instead as the underlying database should be used to carry out the necessary database operations to format and regulate its own data. Using Hibernate to do that removes autonomy from the database below.

Comment: @blackpanther I want to work with different id generation algorithm, but I have started with identity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried changing `generator class="identity"` with `generator class="increment"` as discussed in the following manual: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-generated

Comment: it won't work as it needs initiail value, so am I need to set insert one value manually?

Comment: No, increment should insert a value automatically.

Comment: I have used UUID to generate primary key..any how thanks. I"ll accept this as answer because of your follow up.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure MySQL does not support identity. Or, better said, identity is called auto increment in MySQL. As referenced here http://lists.mysql.com/mysql/6442, you should use auto increment.

Comment: it won't work as it needs initiail value, so am I need to set insert one value manually?

Comment: MySQL does support identity.